# How to get video call log details from twilio Video in Node.js, on server side?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I want to get video call log details from twilio using node.js on the server side.
I need details:

1. what time call started/ended,
2. duration of a call,
3. A time duration for which each participant connected in a call.
4. what time each participant joined/left a call.

All the above details for a completed call.

For the above requirements, I found something:
[Video Log Analyzer API (beta)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/video-log-analyzer/video-log-analyzer-api) on twilio.

But I am not able to understand how can I use this.
There is no SDK provided here. If I try to send a request to the URL then

Curl for this is below
*

```
curl "https://insights.twilio.com/v1/Video/Rooms"
-u {account_sid}:{auth_token}
```

- 

But I don't know how to pass details after -u, i.e. where can I send accound_sid and auth_token in my request. I am trying to use axios to send a request to this URL but where can I pass values of accound_sid,auth_token in the request.

What is -u in curl ?

Can anyone provide me some solution for this or any other idea to achieve my rquirement?

I WAS TRYING SOMETHING LIKE THIS

```
 const URL = "https://insights.twilio.com/v1/Video/Rooms/"+room_SID+"/Participants/"+partcipant_SID;
      const config = {
        headers: {
          //'content-type': 'application/json',
          //'Authorization': token,
          //WHAT TO DO
        }
      }
      axios.get(URL,config)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -u is your Twilio Account SID and Twilio Auth Token, you see the field for it on the main page when you log into your Twilio Console.

[image]

There are also some other API's:

[Video Log Analyzer API (beta)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/video-log-analyzer/video-log-analyzer-api)

[REST API: Rooms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource)

[REST API: Participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/participants)

[REST API: PublishedTrack](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/publishedtrack)

- This show active tracks (not when the meeting is completed)

per your comment below, code example:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const roomSID = 'RM...';
const participantSID = 'PA...';

const ACCOUNT_SID = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID;
const AUTH_TOKEN = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;

 const URL = "https://insights.twilio.com/v1/Video/Rooms/"+roomSID+"/Participants/"+participantSID;
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: URL,
      auth: {
        username: ACCOUNT_SID,
        password: AUTH_TOKEN
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my question. I am actually looking for code in node.js to use, as described in  "Video Log Analyzer API (beta)" link. I have got account SID and Auth Token, but how to use them in node.js to  perform methods described on this link:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/video-log-analyzer/video-log-analyzer-api

Comment: Thank you so much, This is what I was looking for. It worked